# Adding a title to the left side of the navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

Is it possible to add a title to the left side of the navigation bar? I know how I can add a title in the center but when I try to add one to the left side I see nothing. This is the code I have:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Elapsed Time: 0:00"
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title",
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
                                   target: nil,
                                   action: nil)
    leftItem.isEnabled = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

More powerful solution of this problem:

```
let longTitleLabel = UILabel()
    longTitleLabel.text = "Long long long long long long title"
    longTitleLabel.font = ................
    longTitleLabel.sizeToFit()

    let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: longTitleLabel)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

Now you just can edit label as you want. You can use another font or text color.

Comment: @Alex Because in another case you will see animation on tap. It is a button, and it has tap animation.

Comment: It worked but is there a reason it is greyed out? Is it because it is not enabled?

Comment: @Brejuro yes, it is because of it if you want I can write another more powerful solution for this problem

Comment: @Vasyl Would you mind helping me out on that? That would be great.

Comment: @Brejuro Chech answer now

Comment: Awesome it works thanks a lot! But how come I can't add `titleTextAttributes` to `leftBarButtonItem` to change the font?

Comment: Just change longTitleLabel attributes before creating UIBarButtonItem. Check answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76564/discussion-between-vasyl-khmil-and-brejuro).

Answer (score 7):

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: view.frame.height))
    titleLabel.text = "  Home"
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try creating a custom view, and then create a UIBarButtonItem with that custom view in it.

Custom view:

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 14)) // adjust as you see fit

label.text = "Label test"
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

button.addSubview(label)

// Add it to your left bar button

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButtonNegativeSpacer, UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```