# iOS - Custom Navigation Bar with multiline title

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

Can anyone suggest how to effective achieve what appears in the picture below?

[image: Expected outcome with title]

To summarize:

1. The `titleView` is aligned close to the `Back` button. I tried by setting the frame of the `titleView` but it only changes within a fixed bounds
2. The `title` is multiline and left aligned. I guess this can be achieved just by setting the `.textAlignment` and `numberOfLines` properties of, presumably, the `title label`
3. The `title.top` seem to be aligned with `backButton.top`
4. The gray line below the title wouldn't be the `topLayoutGuide` as it seems customizable at least in its length
5. The navigation bar itself is more than `64p` - the default height, and can possibly be calculated?

So far, I have tried adding a `UIView` with a `UILabel` subview to the navigation bar and it sort of works but looks like

[image: What is achieved so far]

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298383/multiline-navigationbar-title)

Comment: No. The problem isn't the "multiline" part, but the alignment of the title with respect to the back button and the height of the nav bar itself

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949969/adding-a-title-to-the-left-side-of-the-navigation-bar)

Comment: Tried it already, didn't work. Thanks for pointing out though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

objective c

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblTitle.text=@"This is a multiline string for the navBar details";
lblTitle.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50);
lblTitle.numberOfLines=3;
self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;
```

swift

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:150, height:50))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    label.numberOfLines = 3
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor
    label.text = "This is a multiline string for the navBar details"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Comment: This was pointed out by @Dopapp and as I mentioned, I have already tried this. This only confines the label within the fixed bounds of navigationItem's titleView.