# move the navigation item Title to the right side of your navigation bar in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to move the navigation item "Qaustion" to the right side of your navigation bar

in Swift in UIKit

```
import UIKit

class ViewController3: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Navigation"
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this your ans ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950022/14733292

Comment: I want the Navigation itself not a lable

Answer (score 0):

Change Content & navigation direction **right to left** or **left to right**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshView()

    navigationController.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    self.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    // or
    // UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    //self.refreshView()
}

func refreshView() {
    let window = self.view.superview
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    window?.addSubview(self.view)
}
```

> Refer -
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute

Comment: Nice, he changed direction but only entered the button ، In the first view, it is still heading to the left

Comment: Nothing happened, the same results

Comment: Nothing changed, I attached a picture

Comment: True, it is all over it

Comment: Over all views and nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

This picture is in this reply
The direction changes only when entering the button

[image]